# MySQL 5.7 ORDER BY field ASC and DESC giving same results

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have a mysql table in my database that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I have the following values in the table:

```
id | title
----------
3  | hello world
1  | goblin
4  | what
2  | asdf adventure
5  | no way
```

In reality, I have thousands of these id's and titles, and so I am limiting the results I get by using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`. When I do the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM test
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 5 OFFEST 0;
```

I get the following:

```
id | title
----------
1  | goblin
2  | asdf adventure
3  | hello world
4  | what
5  | no way
```

This is great so far. But I have an issue when ordering by `DESC`. If I execute the query:

```
SELECT * FROM test
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 5 OFFEST 0;
```

I get the following results:

```
id | title
----------
1  | goblin
2  | asdf adventure
3  | hello world
4  | what
5  | no way
```

But I want this as my result:

```
id | title
----------
5  | no way
4  | what
3  | hello world
2  | asdf adventure
1  | goblin
```

Why is `DESC` not working as intended? Is there something I can do to sort by descending `id` value?

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem at all? Perhaps try sqlfiddle.com for that. If we are unable to reproduce the problem all we can suggest is that you double check your tests.

Comment: Try escaping `id` with backticks

Comment: @AaronD That fixed it.. I just had to escape `id`

Comment: @AaronD... but why?!  That makes no sense.  How is `id` being interpreted when unescaped?  If this behavior is being correctly reported, this is a bug. Has the optimizer lost its mind in 5.7? It's not [a keyword or.reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I'm honestly not sure. What is even more funny is that my friend has the same exact copy of my database, and is also running MySQL 5.7 on El Capitan. Using the query that failed to sort id's correctly on my computer actually succeeded on his. ¯|_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Wish I could answer that, but it was simply a shot in the dark while passing by.  Going off of what Alex posted in his question, the only possible answer was that the optimizer wasn't understanding `id` properly.  Very curious behavior... My best guess is that it is an InnoDB specific bug but I don't have an environment to test that theory.  I know InnoDB has had issues with ordering in the past.. for example https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=31001

Comment: That's a worrying problem.  What minor version is this in?